# Mathematical foundations of Reinforcement Learning

Tags: book-recommendation, machine-learning, operations-research, learning

I'm trying to read and learn about Reinforcement Learning. I found that one of the most popular books about the topic is 'Reinforcement Learning: an Introduction' by Sutton and Barto. However in the preface they point out this:

> We did not reach for the highest possible level of mathematical abstraction

Therefore I was looking for any suggestions of more "mathematical" bibliography.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check this book: [Mathematical Foundations of Reinforcement Learning](https://github.com/MathFoundationRL/Book-Mathmatical-Foundation-of-Reinforcement-Learning), which may well balance the math and intuition.

Answer (score 0):

Some options could be:

1. [Algorithms for Reinforcement Learning](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Eszepesva/papers/RLAlgsInMDPs.pdf) by Csaba Szepesvari
2. [Reinforcement Learning and Optimal Control](https://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/RL_Frontmatter-SHORT-INTERNET-POSTED.pdf) by Dimitri P. Bertsekas
3. MIT lectures by Dimitri P. Bertsekas avaliable [here](http://www.mit.edu/%7Edimitrib/RLbook.html)